# ORACLE REGEX_REPLACE TO REPLACE A QUESTION MARK FOLLOWED BY A NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle

How would you replace a number followed by a question mark again followed by a number.

```
Input          : abc#95988287?3008009095
Desired Result : 95988287
```

I tried:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('abc#95988287?3008009095', '\?[1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]', '')
  FROM dual;
```

and the result was:

```
abc#95988287008009095
```

Please advice how to replace this.

Comment: Do you need to check the length also or any number placed between `#` and `?`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\d` for to match a digit and you need to escape the `?` with `\?`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         'abc#95988287?3008009095',
         '\?\d'
       ) AS replaced_value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | REPLACED_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | abc#95988287008009095 |

---

If you want to replace multiple digits then use `\d+` to match one-or-more digits:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         'abc#95988287?3008009095',
         '\?\d+'
       ) AS replaced_value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | REPLACED_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | abc#95988287 |

---

If you want to return the numeric substring between the `#` and the `?` then you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         'abc#95988287?3008009095',
         '#(\d+)\?',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS replaced_value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Or you can replace everything up to the first `#` and after the `?` using:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         'abc#95988287?3008009095',
         '.*?#|\?\d+'
       ) AS replaced_value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which both output:

> | REPLACED_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 95988287 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bf8e2536e145a3607406693869d26806)*

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want a substring, not a replacement. The following produces the result you're looking for:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc#95988287?3008009095', '#(.*)\?', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
  from dual
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=82a989f8d276c85cd4a8af8ec4d1b92c)